# Glob to match files except certain extension

Tags: python, macos, unix

Newbie to python! I'm trying to use `glob` in conjunction with `max` to find the last modified file in a folder but excluding one type with extension `pdf`. I've tried:

Without the exclude i have this which is working fine:

```
crshLogs = glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*')
currCrshLog = max(crshLogs , key = os.path.getmtime)
```

To try and exclude the pdf I've tried:

`crshLogs = glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'!(*.pdf)')`

and also

```
crshLogs = glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*') - glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.pdf')
```

But in both cases the next line of code fails with `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` so presumably nothing is being returned.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: How about `crshLogs = [x for x in glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*') if x not in glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.pdf')]`?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth that's scanning the directory twice. Better use `fnmatch`

Comment: tried that @NihalSangeeth. Doesn't seem to work. Still returned the PDF?

Comment: Really? Could you give a sample of each of these lists and the returned PDF?

Comment: Wouldn't let me edit earlier! It's my fault. Had the old code line in there still. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
[filename for filename in glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*') if not filename.endswith('pdf')]
```

Also I would change

crshLogs = glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*')

to

```
crshLogs = glob.glob(os.path.join(homePath, crshLogPath, *.*')
```

This will take care of shitty edgecases, like homePath ending not in / and crshLog path not starting with / which would make a mess

Comment: better: `glob.glob(os.path.join(homePath, crshLogPath,'*.*'))`

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried changing the line to `crshLogs = [filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(homePath, crshLogPath, '*.*')) if not filename.endswith('pdf')]` but get a syntax error. Am I misreading something? Cheers

Comment: Yes Change it to filename fpr filename in

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array and not put pdfs in it:

```
file_list=[]
for filename in glob.glob(homePath+crshLogPath+'*.*'):
    if ".pdf" not in filename:
        file_list.append(filename)
```

And then get your filenames from that array.